# How to get transaction count per year in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to get yearly transaction every category

```sql
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, trans_date) AS YEAR, SUM(CAST(doc_no as int))
FROM transac_tbl1 WHERE agent_id IN ('transaction1', 'transaction2')
GROUP BY trans_date
```

Comment: What is the problem with your query?  What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You obviously have an issue with the `GROUP BY`.  I would also suggest the `YEAR()` function:

```
SELECT YEAR(trans_date) AS YEAR, SUM(doc_no)
FROM transac_tbl1
WHERE agent_id in ('transaction1', 'transaction2') 
GROUP BY YEAR(trans_date);
```

I'm not sure why you are casting `doc_no` to an int.  I wonder if you really just want the count:

```
SELECT YEAR(trans_date) AS YEAR, COUNT(*)
FROM transac_tbl1
WHERE agent_id in ('transaction1', 'transaction2') 
GROUP BY YEAR(trans_date);
```